# How to get name of the array inside of array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access name of the array inside of other array in the loop but i am failing. I am able to access name of that array if it's not inside another array by fx. Object.keys({thisObject})[0] but when it's inside of another array it does not work.

I have already tried for each loops, for loops. Nesting initialized arrays in the new array:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3]
var arr2 = [4,5,6]
var arr3 = new Array(arr1,arr2)
```

Still, in the loop i cannot get the name of the arr1 and arr2. I have possibility to access their values but not the names..

```
var cars = new Array("Porshe","Mercedes");
var bikes = new Array("Yamaha","Mitsubishi");

var vehicles = new Array(cars, bikes);


for (var key in vehicles) {
    var value = vehicles[key];// This is retruning whole array, not the name
    console.log(Object.keys({vehicles[key]})[0]) // That does not work
    vehicles[key].forEach(car => {
        console.log(car)

    });
}


//or

for (let i=0;i<vehicles.length;i++){
    console.log(vehicles[i]); //This is also returning whole array - same method.
    for(let j = 0; j< vehicles[i].car.length;j++){
             console.log(vehicles[i][j]);
    }

}
```

The result which i want to get is to listing the cars in the table where Cars are the headline and underneath are the Porsche, Mitsubishi and then Bikes are the next one.

Comment: You are storing arrays in array. They will not have any name, object properties have names not arrays. If you want names then do something like `var vehicles={cars: ["Porshe","Mercedes"], bikes: ["Yamaha","Mitsubishi"]}`

Comment: Ok, so now i am albe to get the array names but when i try to do loop over the elements inside it's giving me number of letters inside the name of the array like:



`var vehicles={cars: ["Porshe","Mercedes"], bikes: ["Yamaha","Mitsubishi"]} 

for( var vehicle in vehicles){

 console.log(vehicle) //That is working fine now

  for( var mark in vehicle){

   console.log(mark) //That's returning lenght of the name of the 
                        array like 0,1,2,3,4,5 for Porshe
  }

}`

Comment: You can do. `vehicles["cars"].forEach(item => console.log(item))` in place of "cars" you can place your variable.

Comment: I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
const map = new Map();
const cars = new Array("Porshe","Mercedes");
const bikes = new Array("Yamaha","Mitsubishi");

map.set('cars', cars); 
map.set('bikes', bikes);
```

You can retrieve them like this:

```
for(let arrayName of map.keys()) {
    console.log(arrayName);

    for(let item of map.get(arrayName)) {
        console.log(item);    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
cars
Porshe
Mercedes
bikes
Yamaha
Mitsubishi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i=0;i<vehicles.length;i++){

     for(let j = 0; j< vehicles[i].length;j++){

         Console.log(vehicles[i][j]); 

     }  

}
```

The variablenames are of no use, when you try to access data... only the object is stored within the array, not the variablenames per say.

Answer (score 0):

that's not going to work, the arrays inside the other array are not properties, and thus have no propertyName. what you want to do, is create an object like so:

```
arr1 = [value1, value2];
arr2 = [value1, value2];
obj = { 'a1': arr1, 'a2': arr2}
```

then you can iterate over the object keys, because now it is an object:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => console.log(key + ' = '+ obj[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
var vehicles={cars: ["Porshe","Mercedes"], bikes: ["Yamaha","Mitsubishi"]};

for( var vehicle in vehicles){ console.log(vehicle)} // this returns the keys in object i.e. "cars" and "bikes" not the values of array

for( var mark in vehicle){ console.log(mark) // this will loop on "bikes" and "cars"
```

To get values you need to do.

```
for(var type in vehicles) { // will give type of vehicle i.e. "cars" and "bikes"
    vehicles[type].forEach(vehicle => { // will get values for each type and loop over them
        console.log(vehicle); // this will print the values for every car and bike
    )};
}
```